# exported methods not available in same package

Tags: go

I have a small go lang project which in the main.go file has a few handlers that refer to session related methods in a session.go file. Both have `package main` at the top of the file. The functions in the session.go file all begin with an uppercase letter (i.e. they are public/exported methods). Yet when I run the `main.go` file, it says the methods located in `session.go` and called from `main.go` are `undefined`. Why is that, how to fix it.

I am running the project like `go run main.go`

main.go

```
func logout(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
ClearSession(w, r)
 ....
}
```

session.go

```
func ClearSession(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

}
```

Comment: You have to run `go run main.go session.go`. The `go run` command needs all the files named.

Comment: ok, thanks, I actually ran go build and got it to work. I guess your answer is the solution if you don't build. If you write the answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ptd said, the command needs all the files named.

I prefer use another package:

```
/ main.go
  |_session/
    |_session.go
    |_validations.go
    |_errors.go
```

So, you can organize your code and simplify your named files.

e.g.:

**file**: main.go

```
package main
import "session"

func main() {
  var validator session.Validator
  var session session.Session
  ...
  if session.IsValid() == false {
     // return session.InvalidSession
     fmt.Printf("ERROR: %v", session.InvalidSession)
  }
}
```

**file**: errors.go

```
import "errors"

var (
   InvalidSession = errors.New("[Your error message]"
)
```

Then you can use:

```
go run main.go
```